# creating web service on php

Tags: php, web-services, web

I am trying to create a web service but I cannot understand what is the problem here.

SimpleClient.php

```
 <?php
include_once("nusoap.php");

try {

// Create a soap client using SoapClient class
// Set the first parameter as null, because we are operating in non-WSDL mode.
// Pass array containing url and uri of the soap server as second parameter.
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => "http://www.example.com/SimpleServer.php",
'uri' => "http://www.example.com"));
// Read request parameter
$param = $_POST['name'];
// Invoke AddHello() method of the soap server (HelloServer)
$result = $client->AddHello($param);
echo $result; // Process the the result
echo "test";
}
catch(SoapFault $ex) {
$ex->getMessage();
echo 'test';
}
?>
```

SimpleServer.php

```
    <?php
include_once("nusoap.php");

// Simple Method get 1 parameter and return with Hello
function AddHello($name)
{
     return "Hello $name";
}
// Create SoapServer object using WSDL file.
// For the simplicity, our SoapServer is set to operate in non-WSDL mode. So we do not need a WSDL file
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>'http://www.example.com'));
// Add AddHello() function to the SoapServer using addFunction().
$server->addFunction("AddHello");
// To process the request, call handle() method of SoapServer.
$server->handle();
?>
```

SimpleView.php

```
  <?php
echo "<h2>Welcome to PHP Web Service</h2>";
echo "<form action='SimpleClient.php' method='POST'/>";
echo "<input name='name' /><br/>";
echo "<input type='Submit' name='submit' value='Send'/>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

No result is shown when I call www.example.com/SimpleView.php and input any word its process to SimpleClient.php.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.phpgang.com/create-a-web-service-with-php_43.html).

Comment: Have you got PHP errors switched off? If you're seeing a blank screen, it probably means that PHP is throwing a fatal error, but is suppressing it due to the config setting. Switch on the error messages, and you should get more info displayed to help you debug the problem. (alternatively look at the server log file, which will contain the same info)

Comment: sorry its error_reporting  = 30711 :S

Comment: also, I note that you're using the NuSoap library. Are you aware that PHP has its own built-in Soap classes that make NuSoap redundant. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: I created a library in the past that Generates WSDL document and handles in/out soap messages. Its very easy, you may look into the following URL: http://asimishaq.com/resources/easy-soap-web-service-php

Answer (score 2):

I checked the tutorial you refered, and it worked for me
just download the code they have given and change the uri parameter in
SimpleClient.php file.

if your apache server is hosted other then port 80 then specify that properly.

I downloaded the code from there and pasted in webroot directory inside 
Web_Service directory.

So SimpleClient.php will look like for port 80

```
<?php
try {
// Create a soap client using SoapClient class
// Set the first parameter as null, because we are operating in non-WSDL mode.
// Pass array containing url and uri of the soap server as second parameter.
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => "http://localhost/Web_Service/SimpleServer.php",
'uri' => "http://localhost/Web_Service/"));
// Read request parameter
$param = $_POST['name'];
// Invoke AddHello() method of the soap server (HelloServer)
$result = $client->AddHello($param);
echo $result; // Process the the result
}
catch(SoapFault $ex) {
$ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

If your server is hosted in different port then specify the port like this.
here I mentioned port 81

```
<?php
try {
// Create a soap client using SoapClient class
// Set the first parameter as null, because we are operating in non-WSDL mode.
// Pass array containing url and uri of the soap server as second parameter.
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => "http://localhost:81/Web_Service/SimpleServer.php",
'uri' => "http://localhost:81/Web_Service/"));
// Read request parameter
$param = $_POST['name'];
// Invoke AddHello() method of the soap server (HelloServer)
$result = $client->AddHello($param);
echo $result; // Process the the result
}
catch(SoapFault $ex) {
$ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in SimpleServer: before use AddHello function , you need rigester it

```
$server->register('AddHello',$name)
```

for more informtion about web service and solve your problem, check this link :
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes